# jQuery ready function not working

Tags: jquery

Chrome, Opra and IE all show the first alert, but do not show any other alert when clicking on the button.

```
<div id="contact-container" style='display:none'>
  <div class="sendConfirmation">
    <div class='contact-top'></div>
      <div class='contact-content'>
    <h1 class='contact-title'>Message was sent !</h1>
      </div>
    <div class='contact-bottom'>
      <a href='http://www.i-home.es/'>International Spanish Student Home, Valencia</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
alert ("Spot 0");
$("document").ready(function() {    
alert ("Spot 1");
    $('#testbutton').click(function(e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        // e.preventDefault();
        alert("Spot 2");
    $('#contact-container').show(5000,function() {alert("is working"); });
    });
    });
</script>

<button id="testbutton" > Click here</button>
```

Comment: Did your include the jquery library? Is the library loaded?

Comment: Did you load jQuery correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem: The position of the inclusion of the jQuery library in the HTML matters.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../emailModalForm/js/jquery.js'></script>
```

I had it towards the end of the HTML document and was not working (at least for this test script, it works for another script... weird). As soon as I moved it up towards the beginning of the HTML file it started working.

Comment: it should really be near the end..but the important thing is that it's before where it's needed, ie before any script that needs it

Answer (score 4):

The following is not correct to the specified HTML:

- No html tag
- No body tag
- No jQuery script include (and no head tag as well) 
  `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

When I add these, everything works like a charm.

Comment: I omitted every thing else for simplicity, to go right to the point. I already have the html, body, jQuery tags. It is good to know that it work for you though. Perhaps there is a conflict with other scripts.

Comment: I found the source of the problem: The position of the inclusion of the jQuery library in the HTML matters. If it is done after the test script, it does not work. If I

Answer (score 1):

i believe it should be $(document).ready instead of $("document").ready

Comment: yeah, I was amazed as well! Didn't know it until I just tried it for the question :P